# How can we find the current direction of a node in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I would like to implement distance measurements between nodes using spherical coordinates. How do we find the direction of a particular node in veins simulation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veins uses planar (x/y) coordinates with 1 unit equal to 1 meter for all of its computations.

(Even the road map uses planar coordinates. To get a planar road map of a real city, the import process for a `.net.xml` file uses map projection - for example, the Veins 4.4 tutorial simulation used UTM projection).

As a consequence, you can use simple trigonometry to get the distance between any two points (or, as most coordinates are stored using class `Coord`, you can call its [`distance`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/base/utils/Coord.h#L179) method.

The recommended way to get the position of any car in the simulation is to call its mobility module's [`getCurrentPosition`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L82) method.

If you absolutely need to determine the longitude/latitude of a given x/y position, you will need to apply the inverse of the map projection used when importing the road map. If this information is present in the `.net.xml` file, this can also be done by calling the [`getLonLat`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L29) function of a `TraCICommandInterface` (obtained, for example, like in the tutorial simulation in [`TraCIDemo11p.cc`, line 34](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L34)).